# Yammer feed duplicating in SharePoint 2016 using Content Editor

Tags: sharepoint-online, yammer, yammer-embed

After I embed my Yammer code in a Content Editor, the feed is too skinny for the space given, but it works fine. After I try to edit something else on the page I get a second Yammer feed right underneath that feed, and sometimes a third. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying and pasting scripts into the Content Editor web part, you should enter the code to a file and store the file in a SharePoint library, then link this file to the Content Editor web part.

You can refer to [this blog](https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2011/03/javascript-duplicating-generated-html-in-a-content-editor/) for more information. It has good information though it is for SP 2010.